# Create image using php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am creating image using php GD library it is working fine but when i use some ajax in it then it occurs some problem like the ajax response is unreadable text. Basically i want to get the image using ajax. My code is given below:

html code:

```
<textarea name="txt" id="txt"></textarea>

Jquery Ajax code:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#txt").change(function() {
        var txt = $("#txt");
        //alert(txt.val());

         var myData = 'txt='+ txt.val(); //build a post data structure


            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Post / Get method
            url: "create.php", //Where form data is sent on submission
            //contentType: "image/png",
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                //alert(response);
                var result = response;

            /*$("#socialline").hide();
            $("#msgline").show();*/

             document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = response;

                //$('.loading').remove();
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });

    });
    </script>

Php file (create.php) code

<?php  
$txt = $_POST['txt'];
    $im = @imagecreate(400, 300) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    imagestring($im, 55, 55, 55,  $txt, $text_color);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    //echo '<img src="image.jpg" />';

    //echo $txt;
    //echo $abc;


?>

The output is something like that

�PNG  IHDR�,�yw�PLTE�[an��IDATh���1 �0��@�@(�C!ࢇi�^@p�Щ���W�x�B����3�H]D��"���?����_ӭ*��Y��?I��d�}g��T''2���U��;���� =%'�N��3}��L8���҇���{��E�-�X�\���7%8o��`IEND�B`�
```

Comment: Why would you think that a PNG `image` is a readable text?

Comment: I have also tried jpg it is also unreadable.

Comment: Yes, that's because they're image files in their specific format and not readable text. What you want to do is to set the image's `src` property to the generated URL, the browser will take care of the rest

Comment: I didn't get your point please help to write specific code, i can understand it well.

Comment: you need to change the create.php code to work with get. then in your $("#txt").change just update the img's src with whatever values < img src="create.php?txt=whatever"/>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Saqlain DON'T COPY PASTE please... I want a genuine solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do (also see @Pekka's comment) is to pass the url (create.php) as the source of your image file.

Basically:

```
<img src="create.php?txt=some%20text" />
```

File create.php:

```
<?php  
$txt = $_GET['txt'];
$im = @imagecreate(400, 300) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 55, 55, 55,  $txt, $text_color);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Please note I altered the POST to a GET (you can't post inside an img, you can use query parameters though). So think of the consequences (url encode the text in the parameter in example).